# Add onepage checkout to custom page

Tags: php, magento, checkout, magento-1.7

I'm messing around with magento and I'm having trouble figuring out how to add the same content from magento onepage checkout to my custom module page.

I **DO NOT wish to override** original checkout page, just create similar one on my own page. 
I already managed to create a controller which extends the OnepageController and redirects me to my custom page.

All advice is welcome!
Thank you in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well recreating the onepage checkout is a long process. But the information you would want to know is this that all the template files for onepage checkout is under template/checkout/ and the layout file for it is in layout/checkout.xml.

If you would like to know what is going under the hood for the onepage checkout read this article it will help you understand what exactly magento is doing for the onepage checkout. Check this article out 
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magentos-onepage-checkout-in-a-nutshell/ .

If any more queries update it here, I will try to give you an answer as best I can.